# Delegates and Func Cast Issue

Tags: c#, linq, delegates

I am new to Linq and Delegates and all that an I have following issue:

I tried this:

```
Func<int> f = () => { return 123; };

Delegate t = f;
```

Visual Studio shows no errors but then I try this:

```
Delegate d = () => return 123;
```

It's not working

Then I tried this:

```
Action a = delegate { Console.Out.WriteLine("test"); };
Delegate x = a;
```

It works, but

```
Delegate j = delegate { Console.Out.WriteLine("test"); };
```

Directly casting seems not to work. Why?

Can somebody explain me please the differences between Delegate (first cap letter) and delegate (all small letters) and `Func<>` and `Action`?

Comment: Related: [Delegate vs. delegate keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779021/delegate-vs-delegate-keyword)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549358/cannot-convert-lambda-expression-to-type-system-delegate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing fact that:

```
Func<int> f = () => { return 123; };
Delegate t = f;
```

is in fact using constructor:

```
Func<int> f = new Func<int>(() => { return 123; });
```

But there is no Delegate constructor taking lambda expression or implicit conversion between them.

Comment: Ok why does then Delegate t has no Invoke() method but Func has Invoke()? What is the difference there?

Comment: Can you source this fact?

Comment: @devhedgehog t has DynamicInvoke(), whild f has Invoke() and DynamicInvoke : see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858340/difference-between-invoke-and-dynamicinvoke

Comment: But if I can do this: Delegate t = f; then why I do need dynamic Invoke when I already know its function and I know the types. What am I missing?

Comment: If the compiler has to wrap a lambda in a `Func<int>` constructor to assign it to a `Func<int>`, *how does it convert the lambda to a `Func<int>` to pass to the constructor*?

Comment: @devhedgehog `Delegate t = f` Then you can do `((Func<int>)t).Invoke()`. But Delegate class simply doesn't have an Invoke method. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.delegate_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What type is Func<int> how can I find the source code of Invoke?